# How to pass a PHP value from one PHP page to another PHP page through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

In my `allcomment.php` page I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        fn: "<?php echo $thelimnid;?>",          
    };
    $.post("loadcomment/fetch_comments.php", data);       
});
```

I want to send the value of `fn` to `fetch_comments.php` page. In `fetch_comments.php` page:

```
<?php
    $fn  = $_POST['fn'];
    echo $fn;
?>
```

but it does not work.

How can do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have a value in $thelimnid? If that variable is null in php, the post request works, but no parameter is sent. Can you add the code where you populate the $thelimnid variable?

Comment: _What_ does not work? The post request? The `echo` statement? Do you get an error? Be more specific

Comment: yes, I have value $thelimnid=15. if I use this var val="<?php echo $thelimnid;?>"; and if i use alert(val); it works but in the fetch_comments.php page error occur undefined index $fn

Comment: Let's go and do `print_r($_POST);` and see if you're receiving good data and which data

Comment: If you check in your debugger (for chrome, or firefox, right mouse and click `inspect element`), check when you do an ajax call in the `network` tab if your `fetch_comments.php` is indeed called. If so, check it's `params`. if it has, check its `response`. if not, you know it went wrong in the `fetch_comments.php`. If it returns a result, then you simply have to target that response and throw that out.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are requests. That means if you make a request for `fetch_comments.php` file you want to get something back (because this is how requests work). If you request coffee in a restaurant you're saying I want coffee and sending money. Your money are transformed into coffee. Same is here: you're requesting something and it's transformed in your `fetch_comments.php` file so this file can return you something back.

Avoid using shorthand ajax and go for it to debug it better:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fn: "<?php echo $thelimnid;?>",
    },
    dataType: "json",
    url: "fetch_comments.php",
    success: function (response) {

    }
})
```

Btw. Your data:

```
var data = {
   fn: "<?php echo $thelimnid;?>",          
};
```

is not going to execute anything in your `fetch_comments.php` file.

Lets send for example something like  that:

```
var data = {
   fn: "sayThat",          
};
```

Then in your `fetch_comments.php` file just do this:

```
if($_POST['fn'] === 'sayThat')
    echo $whateverYouWant;
```

Please also keep in mind that this echo is going back to your JavaScript. In case of ajax example I've send you above this echo will be shown in here:

```
success: function (response) {
    // response is your $whateverYouWant that you echoed                                
}
```

Comment: "_Try to use ajax instead_" Isn't `$.post()` a shorthand for `$.ajax({
  type: "POST" ...`?